# Why is the Inner Core of the Earth solid in spite of being the deepest and the hottest layer of the Earth

Tags: geophysics, core

I have been recently studying about the layers of the earth and I got stuck with the question that why is the inner core of the Earth solid in spite of being the deepest and the hottest layer.

I hope I could gather your support and help other students as well.

Comment: In a word, pressure.  Melting and vaporizing temperatures depend on the pressure.  Think of the way water boils at lower temperatures when you're at higher elevations.